# Counting loops of groups using all elements

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am learning abstract algebra and considering the different ways I could visualize a group. This question is out of curiosity.

I am familiar with the group table and Cayley graphs. However, in attempting another artistic representation of the group $D_3$, I encountered the following question.

Please refer to the following group table on the right and it "stretched" into a list of all possible products.

[image: D3 group table]

Imagining each row of the list as a domino tile (technically, a domino tile would have only two numbers, but you can take the element labelled "1st" and "result").

I wanted to use all domino tiles in a circle, with tiles touching if their colors match. I found the following condensed solution: $(e,r,r,r^2,rf,f,r,r^2f,r,rf,rf,e,r^2,r^2,f,r^2f,r^2,f,r^2f,r,r,rf,r^2,r^2f,rf,r,r^2f,f,r^2,rf,r^2f,r^2,e,r^2,r^2,r,e,r,rf,r^2f,f,r^2,r^2f,rf,r,f,f,e,rf,rf,e,rf,f,r,r^2,e,f,f,e,f,rf,r^2,r,e,r^2f,r^2f,e,r^2f,r^2f,e,e,e)$ Which should be read as "e times $r$ is $r$, $r$ times $r$ is $r^2$, $r^2$ times $rf$ is $f$, ..." and notice it loops or cycles back into itself.

**My question:** How to count many such 'loops' of all products of elements ?

It is likely this already has some terminology for it and I would appreciate being pointed in the right direction as I learn more about abstract algebra and group theory.

Comment: Your proposed solution ends with $r^2f, e, e, e$, but $r^2fe \neq e$

Comment: Thanks! correcting it now. I had missed a comma.

Comment: "$r$ times $r^2$ is $rf$" is not true

Comment: Fixed as well. Good eye.

Answer (score 1):

I'm interpreting that you want a sequence $(x_i)$ of group elements where $x_{i-2}x_{i-1} = x_i$ for all $i$ (similar to a Fibonacci sequence), with indices wrapping around from the start back to the end of the sequence, and such that for each pair $a, b$ of group elements there is an index $i$ with $(x_i, x_{i+1}) = (a, b)$.

Up to cyclically shifting the sequence around, only at most one sequence can exist. Whether or not it exists depends on the group.

By choosing $x_1$ and $x_2$, we know what $x_3$ will have to be, and then those determine $x_4$, which determines $x_5$, and so on. And since you specify that each pair must appear somewhere in the sequence, we could just start calculating from there and get the same cycle, just started later, but still cycling back around.

Assuming I'm interpreting you right, this sequence will not exist for $S_3$, so I think you might have some mistakes. If you start with $(x_1,x_2)=(e, r)$, then you would continue $(e, r, r, r^2, e, r^2, e, r^2, e, r^2, e, \dots)$, which is not cyclic (it's only "eventually cyclic"), and does not even hit every group element, much less every pair of adjacent group elements.

Comment: Maybe you are allowing the dominoes to overlap only by one square instead of by 2?

Comment: If that is the case, I would recommend clarifying that, maybe with some more diagrams of which dominoes are overlapping and how, at least for a small chunk of your solution.

Comment: This is somewhat similar to the concept of sequencing a group, see, e.g., https://ajc.maths.uq.edu.au/pdf/78/ajc_v78_p035.pdf

Comment: Yes! That sounds about right, Dennis. Sequence is definitely the wording I should have used... But I am quite confident of the "solution" posted as it was verified with strips of paper cut from a printout of the list in the picture. Thank you Gerry for the link.

Comment: What I think I misinterpreted is that I assumed that all adjacent strips overlap by 2, that is, like (1,2,3), (2,3,4), (3,4,5), (4,5,6), and so on. But your proposed solution seems to allow skipping some of these, so that some strips only overlap by 1 square, so you could go from (2,3,4) straight to (4,5,6). Can you clarify: are you allowing overlaps of either 1 or 2 squares?

Comment: Yes. If we say a tile is 2 elements (labelled "1st" and "result") then they overlap once. If a tile is 3 elemnts (labelled "1st", "2nd", and "result") then they'd overlap in two squares.